# What does the fopen() function do when I assign it to a variable?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, fopen

I'm a beginner programmer working on a project that requires my code to read characters from an input file, manipulate them without changing the original file, and then print out the modified version to an output file. To do this, I need to use the `fopen()` function at some point in the program, but I'm curious: what is actually happening here? Are the contents of the input file copied into the variable `input1`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input1;

    input1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it just opens the file for read, to copy the content use `fread` or `fgets` and don't forget to `fclose` at the end.

Comment: Please read a C book or tutorial. These will answer your question and much more you will eventually encounter. Rules here require you to have done some research on your own before you ask here.

Comment: FYI, some [C standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), e.g. [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) (or GNU [`libc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)) for Linux (which I recommend using, when learning C). You could study their source code. They are built above [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)

Comment: Apart from using `input1` as an argument to file reading functions (see answer below), you must check it has a valid value before you use it, to be certain the file was actually opened. Such as `if (input1 == NULL) exit(1)`.

Comment: `FILE *input1` defines a pointer. The pointer value `NULL` which is returned on failure, is a defined value that signifies "no value". This is in contrast to a pointer whose value has not been set at all, which is "undefined". Some functions will fail gracefully when passed a `NULL` value pointer, but passing an undefined value will almost always make the sky fall. File handling functions don't even like `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @Olaf Do you have any recommendations for a structured tutorial/book on C?

Comment: @gabacabriel: 1) This question OT, because it is mostly opinion based. 2) I'm sorry, but I learned C without actually reading a book (and the only I read is nothing I will recommend and very, very outdated. Just search, there are some for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `fopen()` is a file *handle*, which is like a token that you can use later to interact with the file. You can pass your `input1` to a function such as `fgets()` or `fread()`, depending on what you want to do with the file next.

The contents of the file are not copied anywhere by `fopen()`.

Comment: Technically `fopen()` returns a pointer to (the address of) a variable of type `FILE`.

Comment: @alk: Yes, that's true, but for a beginning programmer it's probably worth not throwing the word "pointer" in there if you can avoid it. `FILE` is an opaque type anyway, so the pointer doesn't point to anything useful.

Comment: I agree that `FILE`'s members are of no interest, however if going C there is **no** way around pointers, so dare touching them ASAP.

Comment: I disagree. A beginner starting to read files will eventually be confronted with pointers. Actually, he should have learned about pointers before he starts working with files.

Comment: @Olaf: Saying "you should have already learned about pointers" isn't really helpful in answering the question as posed. In fact, the question does not reveal anything about what the OP does or does not know about pointers.

Comment: Which is the reason he better start using a structured tutuorial/book. `fopen` can be found by a simple search. If that is not sufficient, an answer here would be far to broad, as it had to include some of the basics - including the concept of pointers. OTOH, **if** he already knows about pointers, the your claim is obsolete.

Comment: I have no idea what a pointer is. The course I'm taking isn't supplemented by a textbook. In fact, the course is more of a "programming for engineers" type approach so we're only learning things that the professor deems necessary for an engineer to know. Kind of the bare minimum when it comes to the technical details, but with a greater emphasis on problem solving. Thank you for your answer, Greg. Very helpful because another restriction on the project is that the information from the input file cannot be stored in the program.

Answer (score 1):

The fopen function opens a stream for I/O to the file filename, and returns a pointer to the stream.
so,in your statement :

```
input1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

fopen() opens the file argv[1] for reading and the address returned by the function is assigned to input1.This does not involve copying of the contents of the file.

you can then use the file pointer to read data from the file.for example :

```
char c = getc(input1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Read file handling APIs here.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/c-file-handling/